# Loader with use NotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift

I have code:

MainView.swift:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        // Register to receive notification
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainViewControler.StartUpdatingSplash), name: NSNotification.Name("StartUpdatingSplashNotificationName"), object: nil)

        //new code
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainViewControler.FinishUpdatingSplash), name: NSNotification.Name("FinishUpdatingSplashNotificationName"), object: nil)

    }

    @objc func StartUpdatingSplash() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            EZLoadingActivity.show("LoadingMessage4".localized(), disableUI: true)
        }
        print("##### NOTIFICATION STEP: 1")
    }

    @objc func FinishUpdatingSplash() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            EZLoadingActivity.hide()
        }
        // Stop listening notification
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("StartUpdatingSplashNotificationName"), object: nil)
        print("##### NOTIFICATION FINISH STEP: 2")
    }
```

App.swift:

```
var filesToDownload = [FilesToDownload]()
var filesToDownloadPDF = [FilesToDownload]()

struct FilesToDownload {
    var fileInternetUrl: String?
    var fileName: String?
    var savedURL: String?
    var productImageUrl: URL?
    var fileSize: Int
}    

func startDownloadFiles(filesArray: [FilesToDownload], filesType: Int){
        // Post notification
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("StartUpdatingSplashNotificationName"), object: nil)
        for files in filesArray{
            if filesType == 1 {
                print ("PLIKI DO SCIAGNIECIA: \(files)")
                checkRemoteImage(fileInternetUrl: files.fileInternetUrl!, fileName: files.fileName!, savedURL: files.savedURL!, productImageUrl: files.productImageUrl!, fileSize: files.fileSize)
            } else {
                print ("PLIKI DO SCIAGNIECIA PDF: \(files)")
                checkRemotePdf(fileInternetUrl: files.fileInternetUrl!, fileName: files.fileName!, savedURL: files.savedURL!, productPdfUrl: files.productImageUrl!, fileSize: files.fileSize)
            }
        }
    }

func checkRemoteImage(fileInternetUrl: String, fileName: String, savedURL: String, productImageUrl: URL, fileSize: Int){
        remoteResource(at: productImageUrl, fileSize: fileSize) { (isImage) in
            if isImage == true {
                self.saveDownloadFiles(fileInternetUrl: productImageUrl, fileName: fileName, savedURL: savedURL)
            }
        }
    }

    func checkRemotePdf(fileInternetUrl: String, fileName: String, savedURL: String, productPdfUrl: URL, fileSize: Int){
        self.saveDownloadFiles(fileInternetUrl: productPdfUrl, fileName: fileName, savedURL: savedURL)
    }


    func saveDownloadFiles(fileInternetUrl: URL, fileName: String, savedURL: String){
        let cms = ServerConnect()
        cms.downloadedFileFromInternet(fileInternetUrl: fileInternetUrl, directory: savedURL, fileName: fileName ,  completion: { (data) in
            switch data {
            case .succes:
                print("DOWNLOAD: \(savedURL)/\(fileName)")
            case .error(let error):
                //self.errorLoginMessage(txt: "MainView - Error 110: Problem with download images. \(error)", title: "Blad".localized())
                print("")
                break
            }
        })
    }


func downloadedFileFromInternet(fileInternetUrl: URL, directory: String, fileName: String , completion: @escaping completionHandler) {
        if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(directory)

            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: fileURL.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                } catch {
                    NSLog("Couldn't create document directory")
                }
            }
            do {
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileInternetUrl)
                try data?.write(to: fileURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName), options: .atomic)
            } catch let error {
                print("Error : \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

        } 
    }
```

In function startDownloadFiles I start download my files.
I want show loader when files is downloading `(EZLoadingActivity)`.

Currently, after launching the splash `(loader EZLoadingActivity)` application, the splash is visible all the time, it does not hide after downloading all files.

How can I hide these `EZLoadingActivity` after all files are downloaded from the files `FileToDownload / filesToDownloadPDF`?

Comment: where you post "FinishUpdatingSplashNotificationName" this notification??

Comment: I do not send FinishUpdatingSplashNotificationName anywhere. I do not know where to add :(

Comment: First you need to queue up all downloading task and observer that queue and fire notifivation if queue is empty
To queue up task you can use semaphore or DespatchGroup

Comment: you thing about something like this: https://pastebin.com/RbhAfeNy ?

Comment: There is no internet involved in `downloadedFileFromInternet` method. You should fire `FinishUpdatingSplashNotificationName` when you get response(success/failure) from the request. If you can show the actual code where you are making the request then we can help you tell the exact line where you can fire this notification.

Comment: Yep something like that but all downloading task should perform on background thread(non main)

Comment: this is full App.swift: https://pastebin.com/TqDcYE1v , https://pastebin.com/z00CAZ3p

Comment: @SPatel - https://pastebin.com/RbhAfeNy - this code not working. the loader hides itself before downloading all files

Comment: @trifd in the question, you said loader is not hiding at all. Now you are saying loader is hiding itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fire the notification in the below completion

```
let cms = ServerConnect()
    cms.downloadedFileFromInternet(fileInternetUrl: fileInternetUrl, directory: savedURL, fileName: fileName ,  completion: { (data) in

       NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FinishUpdatingSplashNotificationName"), object: nil)

        switch data {
        case .succes:
            print("DOWNLOAD: \(savedURL)/\(fileName)")
        case .error(let error):
            //self.errorLoginMessage(txt: "MainView - Error 110: Problem with download images. \(error)", title: "Blad".localized())
            print("")
            break
        }
    })
```

I noticed few other places where you are making network calls. So if you are showing loader before making request with those methods then you should fire this notification there also. e.g,

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: fileUrl) { (data, response
        , error) in
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FinishUpdatingSplashNotificationName"), object: nil)
}
```

Then in your listener method, you should have the logic to know if its the right time to hide the loader.

**Recommendation** Using the notifications is not a good approach to handle what you are trying to handle. It will add a lot of effort for you to manage race conditions. I would recommend you to check `PromiseKit` or at least use `completion handlers` effectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check your code immediately. Why not use NotificationCenter at all? Would it be better to do something like this: https://pastebin.com/XejJGT9i ?

Comment: This code `if filesToDownload.count > 0 {EZLoadingActivity.hide }` is hiding your loader once the first file is downloaded. Not all. You should not hide loader anywhere except the method fired by the notification. Make standard. In that method check if all files are downloaded then hide.